# Netbeans c/c++ compiler array start at 1 instead of 0

Tags: c++, arrays, netbeans

This is a simplified code to explain the problem:

```
int *nums[10];

*nums[0] = 5;

cout << *nums[0] << endl;
```

The code compiled, but it fails when it executes. So I tried this:

```
int *nums[10];

*nums[1] = 5;

cout << *nums[1] << endl;
```

and it prints out fine. I figured out that array was starting from *nums[1] to *nums[10]
instead of the usual *nums[0] to *nums[10]. I've checked with others who use the Netbeans C/C++ compiler and theirs work as it should. I assume that it is some preference changed within the specific compiler. How do I change it so it works the way it should?

Comment: The compiler is fine, it's your use of `*`

Comment: You need to be a lot more conservative with your assumptions and your figurins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays **are** 0-based. You're running into undefined behavior.

```
int *nums[10];
```

creates an array of 10 uninitialized pointers to `int`.

```
*nums[0] = 5;
```

dereferences an uninitialized pointer. Anything can happen. For it to behave as expected, allocate memory before accessing the pointers:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
   nums[i] = new int;
```

and delete it at the end:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
   delete nums[i];
```

For example, I get a warning in MSVS:

> warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'nums' used

and also a crash :).

Comment: Or maybe just change the array to `int nums[10];` then access with `nums[0] = 5;`. Trying to explain how to use new/delete in this context is probably not a good idea (especially given the OP obvious lack of experience) without first understanding that is exactly what they need. In my opinion this obfuscates the problem and proves the wrong solution.

Answer (score -2):

In C/C++, arrays are always 0-indexed.

I am assuming you want to create an array of integers. If you want to create an array of pointers to integers, check out Luchian's answer.

You declared an array of 10 pointers to integer values. You did not allocate memory for the actual values. That is why you get an error.

You need to allocate memory for the integers. For this, you have two methods:

```
int nums[10];
nums[0] = 5;
cout << nums[0] << endl;
```

or

```
int* nums = new int[10];
nums[0] = 5;
cout << nums[0] << endl;
delete[] nums; // don't forget to delete
```

Comment: I don't see why this was worth a downvote.  It doesn't show how to use `int *nums[10]` correctly, but it's correct that an array of pointers probably isn't needed and shows two viable alternatives.

Comment: @BenVoigt one was mine, but removed. I saw `delete[] nums;` which was wrong in regards to the original question, and only realized afterwards that he had changed the original code.

Comment: -1: Your example makes an array of a completely different type than the OP wants to use. `int` is very different from `int *`.

Comment: @trinithis: It's entirely appropriate to ask why the OP wanted to use that type.  I question it myself.

Comment: When I post examples on SO, I whittle it down to the point where it may seem odd, yet simple. The OP probably actually needed an array of int pointers.

Comment: I assumed that OP wanted to use an array of integers instead of an array of pointers. I got that assumption from his use of `nums[0]=5`. If he wanted to create an array of pointers, he would have had to write `nums[0][0]=5`. I think it was a perfectly valid assumption.

Comment: The OP doesn't have `nums[0]=5`, the OP has `*nums[0]=5`, which means the same thing as `nums[0][0]=5`.